# Passing the column names dynamically for SET in UPDATE query (SQLITE3)

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
UPDATE empInfo 
SET lastName = (SELECT lastName FROM tmp_empInfo 
                WHERE tmp_empInfo.id = empInfo.id),firstName = 
               (SELECT firstName FROM tmp_empInfo WHERE 
               tmp_empInfo.id = empInfo.id) 
               WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp_empInfo 
               WHERE tmp_empInfo.id = empInfo.id) > 0)
```

I am updating two columns in the above query. I want to pass the column and table names in an array and make the query for SET parameters dynamic. Any ideas?

Comment: You may have to resort to dynamic SQL to build query on the fly

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
def update_task(conn, targets, task):
    sql = f''' UPDATE systemData
          SET {targets}                 
          WHERE id = ?'''

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql, task)
    conn.commit() 

target = 'timesWater = ?, timesMinerals = ?'
task = (5, 2, 1)
update_task(conn, target, task)
```

Comment: I am looking for an answer for this question too. The reason why is: You shouldn't use fstrings to pass queries to a database. (Risk of SQL malicious code injection).

I don't have an answer yet, but avoid the use of fstrings.

Answer (score -1):

The replacement of the query is

```
update empInfo
    Set lastName = tmp.lastName,
        firstName = tmp.firstName
    from tmp_empInfo tmp
    where empInfo.id = tmp.id
```

Answer (score -1):

In really complex scenarios you would better use so called dynamic sql where you can construct the query as string and then execute it as sql. In such case it is much easier to add support for dynamic parameters. And here is the link to give you basic idea [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Example where we supply the table name dynamically:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE general_select1 @tblname sysname,
                                 @key     varchar(10) AS
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql = ' SELECT col1, col2, col3 ' +
              ' FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tblname) +
              ' WHERE keycol = @key'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@key varchar(10)', @key
```

Comment: Thanks Borys, but since i am working with SQLite things are not much pretty here..I just need to make a query as a string for the UPDATE statement. The table name and the number of columns will be passed dynamically